# Vim plugin Align fails to work. Can it be installed without vimball?

Tags: vim

I've happily installed the vim Align plugin on my home computer, but on the Red Hat servers at work, the installation doesn't work.  The servers at work have a very old copy (2006) of vimball, which from Googling I know doesn't support more recent vimballs, including Align.  I can't get the systems group (IT department) to upgrade vimball, so I thought perhaps I could simply copy the various files into ~/.vim/plugin by hand. I copied the 3 files from my home system AlignMapsPlugin.vim  AlignPlugin.vim  cecutil.vim, but when I attempt to use Align from within vim I get the following error message

E117: Unknown function: Align#Align

I know that it's seeing the plugin, because when I remove the plugin the error message is different (it says "Not an editor command Align").

Is there a workaround for this?  I love "Align" and would sure like to use it at work as well as at home.

Comment: Thanks to everybody that answered.  Installing vim was going to be nasty because before that I need mercurial and ncurses, and so it went.  Copying the files into .vim/autoload solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{rtp}/plugin` is not the only location where plugin files can be placed. The name of the function suggests that there is at least one file in `{rtp}/autoload` named `Align.vim` (autoloaded functions must have names looking like `path#to#file#with#function#without#leading#autoload#function_name()`, this example is for function located in `{rtp}/autoload/path/to/file/with/function/without/leading/autoload.vim`). But I strongly suggest that if @LucHermitte’s solution is not acceptable, you should use something that supports holding plugins in separate directories. If you used [VAM](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905) all you needed to do (assuming that you have already installed align using VAM) is to look for files in `~/.vim/vim-addons/Align%294` and copy all of them.

**Update**: Forgot to say, you may try to install newer vimball plugin into your `~/.vim`. In order to do this you need copy a file placed in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/vimball.vim` to `~/.vim/autoload` (there is another related file, `/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim`, but it is not likely to be changed). No need to make IT department to upgrade anything, unless the newest version uses the newest vim features.

Comment: Hum ... I may have misread the question -- I read that OP's version of vim didn't support vimballs at all. @OP, If your version of vim supports VAM, go for it, IMO it's the best plugins manager out there -- because of it supports dependencies.

Comment: @LucHermitte VAM still uses the same vimball plugin as used by vim, so it won’t be able to install Align on the server without updating vimball.

Answer (score 2):

Install a recent (/the latest) vim in your $HOME. I've been doing this for ages now. It's the easiest way to get the job done (i.e. to have a proper environment).